# Load image from api url into angular 5 component

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have a component which html structure look like:

```
<img mat-card-sm-image src="{{img}}" />
```

and in typescript

```
constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
    this.img = null;
    this.loadImage();
  }

loadImage = function () {
   this.img = this.loginService.loginImg();
}
```

and login service:

```
loginImg() {
    const url = "http://localhost:59078/api/image/login";
    this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    });
}
```

and the API Core controller

```
  [HttpGet]
  [AllowAnonymous]
  [Produces("image/png")]
  public IActionResult Login()
  {
     var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                        "wwwroot", "images", "login.png");

     return PhysicalFile(file, "image/png");
  }
```

The idea that the image is not loaded... Why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  return result;
});
```

the `return` here does nothing (especially since you aren't returning the http.get itself). The Service should return the observable http.get (without the subscribe) and then when you subscribe to it from your component, you change the `img` variable from inside.

Here's how you can fix it

```
public img: string;

constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
  this.loadImage();
}

loadImage() {
  this.loginService.loginImg().subscribe(result => {
    this.img = result;
  });
}


# Login service:

loginImg() {
  const url = "http://localhost:59078/api/image/login";
  return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' });
}
```

this is unrelated, but you might consider using an Angular lifecycle hook like `ngOnInit` instead of the constructor for initializing variables

```
constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loadImage();
}
```

Comment: This should work. I would like to add two more comments/best practices to it. 1. You can use OnInit hook to call the service instead of constructor, 2. You can use async pipe in html to subscribe to observable