# When to use Blob type to get image from API?

Tags: javascript, angular, blob

I'm a newbie on Angular. I show an image returned by Web API.

So the `imageURL` likes:

```
localhost/get-image/?target=content&sizetype=348x194&id=129
```

And I just bind it to img src.

```
<img [src]="imageURL"/>
```

The `img` shows image exactly what I want.

But I search around how to load an image from API in Angular, the major result is using `Blob` and no one does like what I'm doing. 
Likes these questions.

[Load image from api url into angular 5 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088231/load-image-from-api-url-into-angular-5-component)

[Getting Image from API in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530752/getting-image-from-api-in-angular-4)

[How to get image from rest api using HttpClient in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356471/how-to-get-image-from-rest-api-using-httpclient-in-angular-4)

and a lot of questions about how to use `Blob`

I tried using `Blob` but I don't see the difference.

So I wonder why and when using `Blob`? 
Sorry if this question is so basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decision to use `Blob` or an existing `image URL` is primarily based on what the *server* returns. If it returns a URL to the image on a file system, and you simply want to display it, then that's what you should use.

Some API's store images in a database, in the form of Blobs. In that case, when you retrieve the image, you will not be getting a URL to apply to the `<img>` tag, and instead will need to create an *ephemeral* URL using the data returned by the server e.g `URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);`

So basically it depends on the server, and the UI needs to support the data type that the server returns. There are exceptions of course, where image manipulation etc is required

The example links you provided are related specifically to API's that are returning Blobs

Comments or opinions welcome

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One upvote for you. Sorry for a question basic